# Compactly supported continuous functions as a Tomita algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group with modular function $\delta_G$ and consider $\mathcal{K}(G)$, the set of compactly supported continuous functions $G\to \mathbb{C}$, with the $*$-algebra structure given by
$$(\xi\eta)(s) = \int_G \xi(t)\eta(t^{-1})dt, \quad \xi^\sharp(s) = \delta_G(s^{-1})\overline{\xi(s^{-1})}.$$
This $*$-algebra becomes a left Hilbert algebra for the inner product on $L^2(G)$ (w.r.t. left Haar measure) by viewing $\mathcal{K}(G)\subseteq L^2(G)$.

Consider now the following fragment from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebras II":

[image]

Two questions:

(1) Is $\Delta_G$ the modular operator associated with the left Hilbert algebra $\mathcal{K}(G)$? I.e. is $\Delta_G = S^*S$ where $S$ is the closure of the involution $\sharp$?

(2) To be a Tomita algebra, we must have that $\Delta_G^\alpha$ maps $\mathcal{K}(G)$ into itself. Why is this the case?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that there is a typo: the complex one-parameter group should be $(\Delta_G^{i\alpha})$ instead of $(\Delta_G^\alpha)$.

(1) Yes. This follows from abstract theory, because $\Delta$ is the closure of $U(-i)$ for a Tomita algebra (Theorem VI.2.2) and obviously $\mathcal K(G)$ is a core for $\Delta$. But in this case it's also not hard to show directly: If $\xi,\eta\in\mathcal K(G)$, then
$$
\langle\eta^\sharp,\xi^\sharp\rangle=\int_G \delta_G(g^{-1})^2\overline{\xi(g^{-1})}\eta(g^{-1})\,dg=\int_G\delta_G(g)\overline{\xi(g)}\eta(g)\,dg=\langle\Delta_G\xi,\eta\rangle.
$$
Thus $S_0^\ast S_0\subset \Delta_G$. Then you just have to show that $\mathcal K(G)$ is a core for $\Delta_G$ to get equality.

(2) The modular function is continuous and takes values in $(0,\infty)$, hence $g\mapsto \delta_G(g)^{i\alpha}=e^{i\alpha\log\delta_G(g)}$ is also continuous. And $\Delta_G^{i\alpha}$ simply acts by $\Delta_G^{i\alpha}\xi(g)=\delta_G(g)^{i\alpha}\xi(g)$. Thus $\Delta_G^{i\alpha}(\mathcal K(G))\subset\mathcal K(G)$.

Comment: Isn't this a bit circular? To answer (1) you use the Tomita theory machinery but this is established in (2)?

Comment: Well I meant with the circularity to invoke abstract theory.

Comment: I don't think it is. I don't use that $\Delta_G=S^\ast S$ for (2). But you are right that one should answer (2) first and then use it for (1).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the proof of (2). You say that $\Delta_G^{i\alpha}$ acts in a specific way. It is not even clear to me why $\mathcal{K}(G)$ is in the domain of this operator. Maybe this is somehow obvious?

Comment: Since $\Delta_G$ is a multiplication operator, the domain of its powers is quite easy to determine: You have $D(\Delta_G^{i\alpha})=\{\xi\in L^2(G): \int_G |\delta_G(g)^{i\alpha}|^2|\xi(g)|^2\,dg<\infty\}$. If $\xi\in\mathcal K(G)$, this integral is clearly finite.

Comment: But why is this true? For me, $\Delta_G^{i\alpha}$ is defined using spectral integrals. There is something to verify, right?

Comment: Yes, but for multiplication operators, this all simplifies. If $M_f$ is the operator of multiplication by the measurable function $f$ (with maximal domain), then $M_f$ is self-adjoint and the spectral measure is given by $E(A)=M_{1_A\circ f}$. By approximation with simple functions one can then see that $\phi(f)=M_{\phi\circ f}$ for measurable $\phi$. This should be among the first examples one sees for the spectral theorem.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that the associated spectral measure was so easy to describe in this case. Learnt a lot from your answer/comments!

Comment: You show $S_0^*S_0\subseteq \Delta_G$. How does the fact that compactly supported continuous functions form a core imply that $S^*S= \Delta_G$?

Comment: $S^\ast S$ is the positive self-adjoint operator associated with the closure of the quadratic form $Q_0\colon C_c(G)\to [0,\infty),\,\xi\mapsto\lVert S_0\xi\rVert^2$. As I've shown, $Q_0(\xi)=\lVert \Delta_G^{1/2}\xi\rVert^2$ for $\xi\in C_c(G)$. Since $C_c(G)$ is a core for $\Delta_G$ (in fact, for $\Delta_G^{1/2}$ is enough), the closure of $Q_0$ coincides with $Q\colon D(\Delta_G)^{1/2}\to [0,\infty),\,\xi\mapsto \lVert \Delta_G^{1/2}\xi\rVert^2$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know anything about how quadratic forms relate to unbounded operators. Could you please point out the precise fact about quadratic forms and unbounded operators you use so that I can look up what to study?

Comment: You can also formulate this without any reference to quadratic forms: $C_c(G)$ is a core for $S$ by definition, hence also for $(S^\ast S)^{1/2}$ (remember that $D(S)=D(|S|)$ and $\|S\xi\|=\||S|\xi\|$). Since its also a core for $\Delta_G^{1/2}$ and both operators coincide on $C_c(G)$, we have $(S^\ast S)^{1/2}=\Delta_G^{1/2}$ and hence also $S^\ast S=\Delta_G$.

Comment: Thanks so much!